# ios Programming, using UIImagePicker inside UINavigation controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to implement the following type of UI flow in my project

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHwwk.jpg

So, basically the following option, I have to show in popover, and on the basis of user selection, I have to navigate to next view, and then can come back to my main view.
My approach so far is in my main view, i m creating a popover with a navigation controller. The navigation controller root view controller is a subclass of `UITableView` controller. In `UITableView` Controller, I am presenting the following two options, and when user selects the "Photo Roll" in table view delagate `tableVIewDidSelectROw`, I am pushing like this

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]]
impgPicker.source = // source type to camera roll
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imgPicker animation:YES]
```

but after this line I am getting the crash, I even tried using

```
[self prsentViewController]
```

but same result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and I am running on iOS 5 simulator.

Comment: What are you seeing in the console after the crash?

Comment: Nothing, even i turned on NSZombie enabled, still nothing

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerController is meant to be used as a modal view controller and displayed using the presentModalViewController:animated: method.

You will likely need to define your own view controllers to implement the interface as designed. You can get access to the albums and photos through the ALAssetsLibrary class.